# the borders function in ggplot did not work as expected?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the (spatial) correlation pattern between two variables and overlapped by countries borders. I use `borders()` function with ggplot but the xlim and ylim didn't give the exact limit I expect, instead, they give all the country. I want to have the exact limits to overlap the data.

```
 library(ncdf4)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape)
 library(maps)
 library(stringr)
 library(reshape2)
 library(mapdata)
 library(maptools)
 ncfile <-   nc_open("/Volumes/KIT/CHIRPS/index/correlation/correlation.amm.allindex.nc")

 lon <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "lon")
 lat <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "lat")
 pr <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "prptotcorrel")
 ret <- list ("lat"=lat, "lon"=lon,"pr"= pr)
 ##
 str(ret)
 ######## melt function for pr
 melt_pr <- function(L) {
 dimnames(L$pr) <- list(lon = L$lon, lat = L$lat)
 rett <- melt(L$pr, value.name ="pr") 
  }
  ######
  mpr <- melt_pr(ret)
  head(mpr)
  #
  xlims=range(mpr$lon); xlims
  ylims=range(mpr$lat); ylims

  gcorrelation=ggplot(data = mpr, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = pr)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  borders('world', xlim=xlims, ylim=ylims, colour='black', size=.2) +
  coord_fixed(xlim=xlims, ylim=ylims) +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", 
                   midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), na.value = NA,        name="correlation") +
   theme_bw() +
   coord_fixed(1.3) 
   gcorrelation
```

I expect to have country borders that fit exactly the data.
Here is what I'd like the plot to look like. Here is the image with the countries; I want just to overlap with the exact limit of shaded data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. Without having a sample of your data ([as code](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html)), it will be hard to help. I believe that `coord_cartesian()` will do what you want instead of `coord_fixed()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`coord_fixed()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html) or [`coord_cartesian()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html), use the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters of [`coord_map()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_map.html).

> `coord_map()` projects a portion of the earth, which is approximately spherical, onto a flat 2D plane using any projection defined by the mapproj package.

(As @yake84 suggested, it would be best to present a simplified version of your problem that contains code *and data* so people can run and test their solutions.)

---

Taking a step back, if you are developing fresh code, I'd avoid outdated packages like [reshape](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reshape), [reshape2](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reshape), and some of the spatial functions.  Instead build on their replacements (often developed by the same people) such as [tidyr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyr), [sf](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sf), and the associated functions in ggplot2, such as [`ggsf()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hi @yake84 and @wibeasley, sorry I'm pretty new on Stack overflow, thanks for your suggestions, coord_map() gave the right expected map. Thanks also for the packages suggestion.